# Off Canvas Layout For Twitter BootStrap With Multilevel Menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, responsive-design, submenu

I want to use this http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ with the sidebar as my main navigation.
But I need a navigation with two levels, and the second level has to slide-in like the first level. I was thinking something like this: http://www.marcandrew.net/off-canvas-infinity-push/

Somebody know how to do it?

Comment: The closest I have been able to find is: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/
It's off canvas, two levels, but not three.